# Delphi: how to handle click on PageControl's empty space?

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi 7.
I want to react on click(left) on empty space of PageControl -- on area righter than the last tab shown. How can i do that?[image: Form with pagecontrol]

Comment: I want to make a tab when such clik occurs.

Comment: You might be better off painting a plus sign somewhere up there. Otherwise how will the users discover it? And won't they be hacked off when they click there by mistake and new tabs appear.

Comment: No, all OK, i create tab when DBL click occurs. Plus sign not needed yet. Like in Notepad++

Comment: I'm a super heavy user of Notepad++. I use it hours at a time, every day. I didn't know that double clicking there opens a new tab. I'm sure you'll have discoverability problems unless you provide an alternative means as well as this shortcut.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can handle the click at the parent control of the PageControl. F.i. if the PageControl is placed on a form, the form's 'MouseDown' events will be called for that specified region. The reason is that the PageControl returns `HTTRANSPARENT` for hit test messages for that region, so the mouse messages is directed to the control beneath it.

If that's not OK, you can change how `WM_NCHITTEST` is handled, for example by subclassing the control, or in a derived control:

```
type
  TMyPageControl = class(TPageControl)
  protected
    procedure WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;
  end;

procedure TMyPageControl.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
begin
  inherited;
  if Message.Result = HTTRANSPARENT then
    Message.Result := HTCLIENT;
end;
```

then, the control's `OnMouseDown` event will be fired. Of course you could test for the region before modifying the message's return value, this example was only to show how it would work.